# Strange chain sound happened just once and now bike will occassionally come to a halt and wont move even in neutral for 15 minutes

Tags: motorcycle, suzuki

I've been dealing with an issue for weeks now with my Boulevard M95 (2005).  It's been keeping me off my bike and has been... well let me just describe it and maybe someone has some educated words for me.

The bike keeps locking up completely (gradually but quickly) at times.  When i have noticed it start to happen I have pulled over and then thrbike wont even roll in neutral for about 10-15 minutes.

So here are the most interesting pieces of info I can provide:

LUBRICATION SYSTEM

Oil was changed recently before the issue started happening (20w-50 mobile synthetic).  I filled it on the low side as this was recommended to me for older cruisers.  Problem seems to happen less after filling it more... closer to H.  I added oil to get the level to H after it was previously in the center between L and H.  The problem happens less often now but ai cant add more oi without going over H.
During an oil change I also discovered that the cylindrical oil screen was kinked,  which I fixed.

COOLING SYSTEM

Radiator fluid becomming darker. Ive already bled the coolant fluid system.

BRAKE SYSTEM

All brake calipers and master cylinders have sinve been bled.

CHAIN SOUND

For about 5 seconds... it sounded like a chain sliding off a cog or a piece of metal hitting several  the links on a chain.  i have only heard this once in 2500 miles.  it happened while coming to a stop or being completely stopped already at a stoplight i dont recall which.

.................

I guess the next step would be opening up the crankcase to check out the chains right?
So, the manual tells me that four chains exist in the bike?

Front Camshaft Chain

Rear Camshaft Chain

Water Pump Chain

Water Pump Sprocket Chain

Any info would be appreciated... novices or experts... thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the site. Does the engine continue to run even if the bike won't roll?